# Google charts scatterplot turning OFF autoscaling

Tags: gwt, google-visualization

I am using a GWT scatter plot. Data values are going to range from 0 to 100 and are arriving in in time. I am plotting the data points as they arrive as a time sequence. I would like to fix the range of y values so that the y axis does not auto-scale. Right now, the max and min y values keep changing with time and this is quite confusing to the user.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

Regards,

Ranga

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do this. Create a vertical axis and set the max and min values for that vertical axis. Then use that vertical axis to create the plot.

```
                VAxis vaxis = VAxis.create("Occupancy %");
                vaxis.setMaxValue(100.0);
                vaxis.setMinValue(0);
                occupancyPlotOptions.setVAxis(vaxis);
```

Hope the answer (to my own question) helps others.

Ranga